Why doesn't the statement after await continue to execute after promise resolves?
I want to implement an asynchronous task scheduling. This is my code:
let gameTick = 0;

const tasks: Record<string, Function[]> = {};

function sleep(t: number) {
    const targetTick = gameTick + t;
    if (!tasks[targetTick]) {
        tasks[targetTick] = [];
    }
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        tasks[targetTick].push(resolve);
    });
}

async function task1() {
  print('start task1');
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    print(`execute: ${i}`);
    await sleep(2);
  }
}

// task1();

for (gameTick = 0; gameTick < 10; gameTick++) {
    print(`tick: ${gameTick}`);
    tasks[gameTick]?.forEach(f => f())
    if (gameTick == 2) task1();
}

This code behaves differently in the TypeScriptToLua environment and in the node.js environment, which confuses me.



TypeScriptToLua
nodejs




tick: 0
tick: 0


tick: 1
tick: 1


tick: 2
tick: 2


start task1
start task1


execute: 0
execute: 0


tick: 3
tick: 3


tick: 4
tick: 4


execute: 1
tick: 5


tick: 5
tick: 6


tick: 6
tick: 7


execute: 2
tick: 8


tick: 7
tick: 9


tick: 8
execute: 1


tick: 9




I can understand the process of TypeScriptToLua, which is equivalent to resuming the coroutine after resolve and immediately executing the code after await. But I don't understand NodeJs. Why does it continue to execute after the loop ends, and only execute once?

Timing errors
The nodejs code is working as programmed. This answer does not look into lua code output except to say it's not following the same timing rules as JavaScipt.
The timing error arises because


   for (gameTick = 0; gameTick < 10; gameTick++) {
      print(`tick: ${gameTick}`);
      tasks[gameTick]?.forEach(f => f())
      if (gameTick == 2) task1();
   }



executes a synchronous loop, calling task1 with gameTick set to 2, and exiting the loop with gameTick set to 10.

The first iteration of the loop in task1 calls sleep(2) which sets up a task for gameTick = 4, before await causes task1 to return a promise to the caller.

The loop in step 1 continues iterating and fulfills the task promise for gameTick 4.

The loop in 1 has finished, and the await operator in task1 returns to its surrounding loop code after "execute 0" has printed. The next iteration of the loop in task1 calls sleep(2) with i set to 1 and gameTick set to 10 (by completion of the loop in 1).

sleep(2) sets up a promise for a task at gameTick 12. This promise is never fulfilled in posted code, leaving task1 waiting for it with execute 1 left as the last line printed.


Short Answer
The await doesn't return because the promise hasn't been resolved.
Debugging
This first snippet added some output to show the value of i and gameTick in more places and log when await returns. It was used to uncover and confirm why the await promise operand was not fulfilled.


function print(txt) {document.querySelector('#log').textContent += txt + '\n';}

let gameTick = 0;

const tasks = {};

function sleep(t) {
    const targetTick = gameTick + t;
    if (!tasks[targetTick]) {
        tasks[targetTick] = [];
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        tasks[targetTick].push(resolve);
    });
}

async function task1() {
  print('start task1');
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    print(`execute: ${i}`);
    await sleep(2);
    print(` sleep await done with i = ${i}, gameTick now ${gameTick} `);
  }
}

// task1();

for (gameTick = 0; gameTick < 10; gameTick++) {
    print(`tick: ${gameTick} tasks length = ${tasks[gameTick]?.length || 0}`);
    tasks[gameTick]?.forEach(f => f())
    if (gameTick == 2) task1();
}

// fix

function hammer() {
    print ("\n **** hammer fix **** ");
    for (let targetTick =10; targetTick < 20; targetTick++) {
        print(`tick: ${targetTick}`);
        print(`tick ${targetTick} tasks length = ${tasks[targetTick]?.length || 0}`)
        tasks[targetTick]?.forEach(f => f())
    }
}
setTimeout(hammer, 2000);
setTimeout(hammer, 4000);
<pre><code id=log></code></pre>



Solution

Run the clock for game ticks asynchronously
Don't use synchronous loops to test sleep and/or initial scheduling of a task.
The example clock code below reports the tick value it uses to look up task arrays of resolve or task functions it needs to call. It then increments gameTick after  processing such an array if found. This implies:

gameTick values obtained outside the clock will be one more than the last tick number processed by the clock.
The example schedule function below, called with zero ticksLater, will call the task function at the next clock tick.





function print(txt) {document.querySelector('#log').textContent += txt + '\n';}

const tasks = {};

function sleep(t) {
    const targetTick = gameTick + t;
    if (!tasks[targetTick]) {
        tasks[targetTick] = [];
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        tasks[targetTick].push(resolve);
    });
}

async function task1() {
  print('start task1');
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    print(`execute: ${i}`);
    await sleep(2);
    print(` sleep await done with i = ${i}, gameTick now ${gameTick} `);
  }
}


//*****  Asynchronous clock *****

let gameTick = 0;
function clock() {
  print("tick: " + gameTick);
  tasks[gameTick]?.forEach(f => f())
  ++gameTick;
}
let clockTimer = setInterval(clock, 100) // start clock running at 10hz for example

//**** scheduler

function schedule( task, ticksLater) {
   const t = gameTick + ticksLater;
   if( !tasks[t]) tasks[t] = [];
   tasks[t].push(task);
}

//**** Test ****

schedule(task1, 2);
schedule(function() {
   print("Simulate game end, clock stopped ");
   clearInterval( clockTimer);
}, 30);
<pre><code id=log></code></pre>




The problem is that promises are asynchronous, but your game loop is synchronous. When you call resolve(), that does not directly continue executing the coroutine. It only resolves the promise, which schedules any registered promise reactions (such as the continuation of the asynchronous code that awaited that promise, or callback functions added via .then()) to run soon, in the next microtask. So you'll need to give it some time to do that before running the next game tick:
(tasks[2] ??= []).push(task1);

let gameTick = 0;    
while (gameTick < 10) {
    print(`tick: ${gameTick}`);
    tasks[gameTick]?.forEach(f => f())
    await Promise.resolve(); // if not even setTimeout()
    gameTick++;
}


Running jobs in the microtask queue from synchronous code may not allow the posted code  to handle real world asynchronous tasks that require returning to the event loop for some time.

@traktor Yes, that's why I suggested a setTimeout in the game loop. Or maybe more appropriately, requestAnimationFrame? But I'm not sure what kind of tasks the OP expects to run, maybe they want coroutines and would be happier with a generator-function based solution.
